# awk match search patterns and print immediate next line's 4th & 5th values

Tags: unix, awk, nawk

I want to match the pattern of 4th and 5th value if they matches print Nextline's 4th and 5th value.

Below is the input file

cat

```
CL3-A3-2  0    0 17496  2851 P-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2850 -
CL3-C2-5  0    0 66319  2850 S-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2851 -
CL3-A3-2  0    1 17496  2852 P-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2851 -
CL3-C2-5  0    1 66319  2851 S-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2852 -
CL3-A3-2  0    2 17496  2853 P-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2852 -
CL3-C2-5  0    2 66319  2852 S-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2853 -
CL3-A3-2  0    6 17496  2857 P-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2857 -
CL3-C2-5  0    3 66319  2857 S-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2857 -
CL3-A3-2  0    6 47496  2857 P-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2857 -
CL3-C2-5  0    3 18496  2857 S-VOL PAIR ASYNC      0  2857 -
```

For Ex: I'm matching 17496 and 2857, If the search pattern matches in a line, Need to get the immediate nextline's 4th and 5th value using awk or sed is fine.

output would be like

66319 2857

Which reduce my duplication while matching pattern

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use the quote functionality for the contents of your input file so that the newlines are visible clearly.

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward:

```
lastMatched {
    print $4, $5;
    lastMatched = 0;
}

$4 == 17496 && $5 == 2857 {
    lastMatched = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if (flag==1) {print $4,$5; flag=0}}
     {if (($4==17496)&&($5==2857))flag=1}' inputfile
```

If you need only one match and want to terminate afterwards simply add an exit.

```
awk '{if (flag==1) {print $4,$5; exit}}
     {if (($4==17496)&&($5==2857)) flag=1}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see a match I raise a flag, if the flag is raised I lower the flag and print the data.

```
% awk 'p==1{p=0;print $4, $5} $4==17496&&$5==2857{p=1}' your.data
66319 2857
%
```

The order of the statements is crucial, if I'd first set the flag and then check it, I'd print `$4` and `$5` for the same line...

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it with below line

```
nawk '/'$4'  '$5'/{getline;print $4,$5}'
```